# Decoding foreign language characters in url

Tags: .net, url, .net-3.5, decode, urldecode

I am decoding characters in a URL by using HTTPUtility.URLDecode. Here are the characters I have to decode:

%26 = "&"
%28 = "("
%29 = ")"
%20 = " "
%5B = "["
%5D = "]"
%2C = ","
%23 = "#"
%F3 = "ó" (spanish character)

HTTPUtility.URLDecode works great on all but the last one. I am doing a find/replace on that last character right now, but hoping there is a better automatic way so I don't have to update the find/replace in the future.

Comment: I think URL characters are supposed to be UTF-8 encoded. It looks like whoever is constructing that URL is using ISO-8859-1 encoding instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [an overload of `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` that accepts an encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sacf9e4b.aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%F3", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
```

This assumes it actually is using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. If it uses Windows-1250, you should use that. (These two are very similar, but they are not the same.)