# "Ø" as input in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, user-interface, gui-testing

I'm working on automating GUI-testing at my job. I'm currently stuck at something as silly as inserting the character "ø", which is a letter of my language.

The method-call is as follows:
`_atlas.AvailabilityRadioSearch.InsertAddressAddress("kjøita");`

This is supposed to automatically fill in the value in a standard textbox on the webpage. But, I can't seem to get it right. It always turns out "kj?ita".

Does anybody know how I can go about fixing this?

Oh, and btw;

Please do not care about the crappy method- and classnames, as this is just for testing-purposes and not to be used by anyone else :)

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: As this is a huge system, and I'm only working on a small part of it, I'm not sure actually :$

Comment: Can you post the code of the InsertAddressAddress method?  Specifically, what method is it calling to insert the data into the UI?  Also, what happens if you type that character into the UI manually, as a user would?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970021/decoding-foreign-language-characters-in-url

Comment: public void InsertAddressAddress(string address)
        {
            _addressForm.Find("_txtStreetName").Text = address;
        }

Comment: Look up what encoding means. You would do good to read this article by Joel Spolsky: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change 'ø' into `&oslash;`

Comment: Same problem I had to begin with. "kj?ita".

Comment: What kind of encoding are you using? And what if you try: `&#216;` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Think about setting the UI Culture/Culture on your page:

web.config

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <globalizationculture="FR-CH" uiCulture="FR-CH" /> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Page

```
<%@Page Culture="FR-CH"  uiCulture="FR-CH"  Language="C#" %>
```

Replace FR-CH with your specific language culture and you should be good to go.

[MSDN UI Culture/Culture for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

[Displaying French in ASP.NET Textbox](https://forums.asp.net/t/1728305.aspx/1?How+to+display+French+characters+in+a+textbox)

[List of UI Culture values (eg FR-CH)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and it works, despite being clunky:

```
char oSlash = '\u00F8'; //use '\u00D8' for the uppercase version
_atlas.AvailabilityRadioSearch.InsertAddressAddress("kj" + oSlash + "ita");
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me :( I'll be back tomorrow. Thanks for the effort guys!

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this problem lies within the in-house developed framework we use for this kind of testing. Seems to me after a bit of research that the browser accepts "ø" in every way possible.