# Encoding in RedirectToAction of a string parameter

Tags: c#

In a controller of mine, I have to following call

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignIn", new { message = GeneralRes.General_ExpiredLink, area = "", language = language });
```

The string in the general res contains a few characters in Spanish (¡ ¿ ... ).

I put a breakpoint in the controller, and the message is ok, but after it goes to a View, and the message parameter is encoded... I get this special characters as `&#161; &#191;`

I tried to do in the View the following -> `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Model.Message)` but without any luck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to find out your solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970021/decoding-foreign-language-characters-in-url

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I tought... What I needed to do, is the following in the View

```
@Html.Raw(Request["message"])
```

Not even needed to use my model :)

Comment: Be careful with Html.Raw that could set you up for an XSS attack especially since you're just outputting something from the request object.