# iOS URI Scheme doesn't accepts multilingual characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uri, uri-scheme

I'm new to iOS planet!

i need to set a URI scheme for my app like: `myappname://` to open my app from email clients.

But now, if my app name has jpn characters or other language characters like `myappname日本語://`

Will it work as normal(URL querystring reads multiligual characters) or what i need to do?

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In iOS URI scheme , there is requirment of convert multi language char via encoding of URL.Let us take a example in which URL contains the other language char.

```
   NSString *string = @"http://test.com/teståäötest";

   NSLog(@"url with string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:string]);
   NSLog(@"url with escaped string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:
   [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]);
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: thanks for your reply. Arpit, the URL will be generated from .NET application so I need to do URL ENCODE at .NET app But will it support URL decode to read at iOS end?

Comment: Check this link for your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970021/decoding-foreign-language-characters-in-url